# What does "Posts %" mean in user's profile page?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

In profile page, there is "Posts %" under top tags which is 100 of mine. What does it mean?

Comment: 100? It shows 95 for me...asking this question invalidated your point ;)

Comment: It is changed after I asked this question.:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the percentage of your total posts that contain that tag.

You've 18 posts tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support) out of 19 total posts which gives you 95% (rounded to the nearest whole percentage)

Comment: All of my 19 questions are tagged "support". Should it be 100%?

Comment: Yes, it is 100 now. But it was not right when I ask a new question, and it changed to be right after several hours. Is it a bug?

Comment: Unlikely, more likely just caching.